# Update <\DATE> as part of string in MSAccess & MySQL saves <DATE>

Tags: mysql

When I need to store a dates or dates+time as part of a string, I save them as double values and pad them with in-house separators - start `</DATE>` and end `<\DATE>`, like this .. `</DATE>doublenumber<\DATE>`.

I feel this takes care of regional settings on different PCs. 'doublenumber' is the value representing the date or datetime.

In MS Access as well as in MySQL the updated stored value in a text field is as follows -

`</DATE>doublenumber<DATE>` so naturally when retrieving the data and decoding/parsing, the code drops out as it does not find the proper end-separator `<\DATE>`.

I adopted the workaround of changing the end separator to `<|DATE>`.

My question is, why is the update statement dropping the `\` in `<\DATE>`?  And I did not notice this till this week.  While having been using this code for at least 2 months before.

To clarify.  I did stop the code before the .execute statement to check the value to be updated and it contained the proper end-separator.  But in the database, the `\` went missing.

Comment: how did you view the "raw" data in the database? PHPMYADMIN or the console or something else?

Comment: In HeidiSQL when using MySQL and by opening the MS Access database when using MS Access.

Comment: UPDATE db1 SET vuid='4222772114FBBEA',
....
Etc.  update statement shown here on different lines for ease in reading.
....
recdata='SIGNED: </DATE>44003<\DATE>',
Etc.  
where uid='060506767083CCADC'

After execution, in the table, recdata reads 'SIGNED: </DATE>44003<DATE>',  (backslash is truncated. Funny thing, noticed it only in the last week.  At first did a find and replace in the development table but when it happened again and again, stopped the code at the ".execute" line to inspect if the correct string is passed to .CommandText).  Before that, all OK regarding this symptom.

Comment: "I feel this takes care of regional settings on different PCs" - What do you mean? Both MySQL and Access have dedicated date/time column types. Whatever, your symptoms regarding backslashes suggest you're injecting raw data into SQL code somewhere, which is a problem of its own know as SQL injection (luckily, trivial to fix).

Comment: Since the beginning of my parttime coding did not like date and time fields &have adopted the policy of storing dt+time as double. Decimal sep of Win & Excel can be diff on the same PC and diff with users fm diff regions.  So if a string has a date, I manipulate it, see recdata above.  This post issue shares the symptom of truncated backslash in my in-house separator <\DATE>.  And the only thing I can think of is Windows 2004 update after around which time this truncation was noticed.  As the code is used 100s of times in the last 2 months, it would have been noticed earlier but was not.

Comment: Doing something that is not best practice makes programs harder to maintain.

Comment: On a hunch, tested. Found that like the apostrophe, the update statement with a backslash must be padded with a second backslash. So the .CommandText= string part should be <\\DATE>. Then in the table <\DATE> would be updated. If a text is to be updated with x\y, the commandtext must have x\\y. That would be an appropriate comment as an example of syntax and best practices. Why it was not manifest and discovered before these last seven days or so when that part of the coding is very fundamental to the software being built, I will never know. BTW, Any other such characters needing doubling?